# Run background process in Sinatra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, background, sinatra

I have got Sinatra/Rails app and an action which starts some long process.

Ordinary I make a queue for background jobs. But this case is too simple and background process starts very rarely, so queue is an overhead.

So how could I run background process without queue?

```
get "/build_logs/:project" do
  LogBuilder.new(params[:project]).generate
  "done"
end
```

I've tried to make it as a new Thread or Process fork, but it didn't help.

Comment: I have been recommended foreverb once. it's not rails specific, it's quite light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had success with this (simplified) in Sinatra:

```
get '/start_process'
  @@pid = Process.spawn('external_command_to_run')
end
```

This returns the Process ID, which you can use to terminate the process later if you need. Also, this is on Linux, it will not work on Windows.

Comment: You are probably looking for your server to return without waiting for the child process to terminate - that's a fairly typical use case. If you don't want zombie processes populating your system (I once saw a server crash after a few months' worth of zombie processes ate up the process map space), you should also add `Process.detach @@pid` after you have `spawn`ed it.