# How to test background process in RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra, background-process, ruby-1.9

Found this simple way to run a separate process in Sinatra: [Run background process in Sinatra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911566/run-background-process-in-sinatra)

```
get '/start_process'
  @@pid = Process.spawn('external_command_to_run')
end
```

How would you test this in RSpec?

Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract a class which does the background processing and unit-test it. Then test expectation that your action invokes method on this class

Some "pseudocode":

```
before do
  MyWorker.should_receive(:perform)
end

specify { get :something }
```