# Testing background processes in nodejs (using tape)

Tags: node.js, testing, tdd

This is a general question about testing, but I will frame it in the context of Node.js. I'm not as concerned with a particular technology, but it may matter.

In my application, I have several modules that are called upon to do work when my web server receives a request. In the case of some of these modules, I close the request before I call upon them.

**What is a good way to test that these modules are doing what they are supposed to do?**

The advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13776563/986415) for RSpec is to mock out the work these modules are doing and just ensure that the appropriate methods are being called. This makes sense to me, but in Node.js, since my modules are not global, I don't think I cannot mock out functions without changing my program architecture so that every instance receives instances of objects that it needs<sup>1</sup>.

[1] This is a well known programming paradigm, but I cannot remember its name right now.

The other option I see is to use `setTimeout` and take my best guess at when these modules are done with their work.

Neither of these seems ideal.

Am I missing something? Are background processes not tested?

Comment: Have you tried testing those modules in isolation?  Like, rather than testing the whole integrated system, have you tried writing tests for each individual module, simulating what they'd get handed from the main process?  Whenever I do a background process, that process will some object or collection of objects.  Those can be executed independently of whether or not they're in a background process.

Comment: Yes, I have unit tests for the modules and they can be executed independently. Is it not normal to have integration tests for these?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are speaking of integration tests of these background components, a few strategies come to mind.

1. Take all the asynchronicity out of their operation for test mode.  I'm imagining you have some sort of queueing process (that could be a faulty assumption), you toss work into the queue, and then your modules pick up that work and do their task.  You could rework your test harness such that the test harness stands in as the queuing mechanism and you effectively get direct control over when the modules execute.
2. Refactor your modules to take some sort of `next` callback function.  They would end up functioning a bit like Express's middleware layer or how `async`'s `each` function works, but into each module you'd pass some callback that you call when that module's task is complete.  Once all of the modules have reported in, then you can check the state of the program.
3. Exactly what you already suggested-- wait some amount of time, and if it still isn't done, consider that a failure.  `Mocha` *sort of* does that, in that if a given test is over a definable threshold, then it's a failure.  I don't like this way though, because if you add more tests, they all have to wait the same amount of time.